# Chomsky: "John is too clever to expect us to catch"

Tags: meaning, syntactic-analysis

This is one of several sentences Chomsky uses to make a point. The point itself is not my concern, but something which is much humbler - how does the following interpretation come about?

There are two sentences:

1. John is too clever to expect us to catch Bill.
2. John is too clever to expect us to catch.

Now, I understand (1), that "John is clever enough to think that we cannot catch Bill". But Chomsky says about (2) in his words, "John is so clever that an arbitrary person cannot expect us to catch him (John)".
How come? How does this arbitrary person get in?

I'm not a native speaker of English but I just don't get it. It's like some weird maths thing that I'm incapable of grasping; and that's scary.

Can someone give some other instances of the exact structure?

Comment: Regarding "How does this arbitrary person get in?" - In #1, John is the one doing the expecting. But in #2, the one doing the expecting is neither *John* nor *us* - the sentence doesn't specify the person.

Comment: okay,.... it's still not intuitive enough. but I think I get it.
more like "that thing is too big to expect us to climb"
cool! Thanks. :)

Comment: I find the structure in #2 a bit awkward, but perhaps this example might help: "The pencil is too blunt (for the teacher) to expect us to write with." Here, it's the teacher that does the expecting. Applying this structure to #2, you can insert (for anyone) after *clever*.

Comment: It's an odd construction. Think of 'to expect' as meaning 'for anyone to expect this.'

Comment: It might help to consider *The syntax of this sentence is too complex to expect you to parse*. In that one, there's no scope for you to be misled into thinking it asserts that the *syntax itself* has no such expectations. Chomsky's example is a bit of a "garden path" construction, because initially we naturally assume we're being told that (because he's too clever) ***John*** doesn't expect something. It's only when we don't find the expected object - *...to catch **him** [John]* - that we realise it's all gone horribly wrong, and we need to re-parse.

Comment: ... note that if we switch to a different verb that could more reasonably be used without an object, the awkwardness goes away. *John is too clever to expect the police to prosecute* works fine for me, regardless of whether *in context* the most likely missing object is *...to expect the police to prosecute **him** [John]* or *...to expect the police to prosecute **the mugger** [who robbed John]*.

Comment: "too complex to expect you to parse", that's a bit rude! Well, but true. :)
And yes, he is giving examples of garden path sentences which I couldn't understand. So thanks!
I wonder if garden paths always require double-parse! Did you reread it the first time?

Answer (score 1):

I found the Chomsky article at [http://www.pitt.edu/~perfetti/PDF/Chomsky.pdf](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Eperfetti/PDF/Chomsky.pdf) and the section you asked about is on pages 9 and 10.

He says that the weird stuff going on in sentences (1) and (2) is similar to some other weird stuff in the following, which I will call sentences (3) and (4) (but note that Chomsky's numbering is different):

> 3. John is too stubborn to talk to Bill.
> 4. John is too stubborn to talk to.

Here, the second, weird, sentence (4) is easier to understand than the weird sentence involving catching (2).  (4) means

> John is so stubborn that some arbitrary person won't talk to him. *(Chomsky's explanation)*

My explanation, in case it helps:

> John is just too stubborn to be talked to.  In other words, John is so stubborn, nobody can talk to him.

It's kind of like an optical illusion (trompe l'oeil), where if you look at something one way, you see one thing, but if you look at it another way, you see something quite different.

Here again is the sentence you asked about:

> 2. John is too clever to expect us to catch.

I find that my understanding of this is quite fleeting.  I sort of see it very briefly, but then when I try to concentrate on it, whoosh, it's gone, and I'm confused again.  But I find it easier to hold onto Chomsky's point of view in a simplified form:

> 2a. John is too clever to catch.

meaning that John is too clever to be caught, i.e. for anyone to catch him.

I hope you're starting to get it, I think that's the best I can explain it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the same as how "this pepper is too spicy to eat" means "this pepper is so spicy that an arbitrary person cannot eat it."

The "arbitrary person" gets in simply because there is no explicit subject of the infinitive verb that comes after the "too ADJECTIVE to...". Since there is no explicit subject, the subject of the verb has to be inferred using rules of syntax, which evidently permit the interpretation "an arbitrary person" in some cases for omitted subjects in contexts like this.